# How to replace data-v attribute from string?

Tags: javascript, string

I have a string like this

```
<h1 data-v-9d995492="">Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h1> <p data-v-9d990000="">Sit amet</p>
```

and I want to remove every string start from data-v- and ends with ", so the result will be like this

```
<h1>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h1> <p>Sit amet</p>
```

How to do that? thanks

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('[data-v-9d995492]').forEach(e=>e.removeAttribute('data-v-9d995492'))`

Comment: what if I have different attribute, eg: data-v-1000000 and data-v-1111111 ?

Comment: Then that's a different question to the one you asked.

Answer (score 0):

I found this way, maybe not good answer but it's work

```
string.replace(/\b data-[\w-=""]*/g, "")
```